# VBA Code to Save PPT Slides as PNG Files While Ignoring Hidden Slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PPT than can have any number of slides, any one of which may be hidden when needed. I have a macro written to save the presentation as png images, but it will save every slide (including hidden slides) as separate images. I want it to save all EXCEPT the hidden slides. Does anyone know of a way to either Export or SaveAs that will skip over the hidden slides? When I export it as a PDF it will automatically ignore the hidden slides, but that is not the case with png files.

Code that saves all slides, including hidden slides:

```
ActiveWindow.Presentation.SaveAs filenamepng, ppSaveAsPNG 'Save the.png files for each slide.
```

I see there are options to not "print" hidden slides, but I see no similar options for saving png images. Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: You'd need to loop through the slides one at a time and if the slide is visible, then use the slide's .Export method to save the slide as an image. Alternatively, create a copy of the presentation, delete any hidden slides, then use Presentation.SaveAs and finally delete the copy presentation. The first method will be more generally useful for many reasons. Each slide's .SlideShowTransation.Hidden property will tell you whether or not it's hidden.

Comment: Ok, great. I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveRindsberg That worked perfect. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked, but I didn't do much more than provide a push in the right direction. You made it work. It'd be much more useful to the SO community if you'd post your working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SteveRindsberg's comment I was able to come up with the following code that solved the problem.

```
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

    i = 1

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    On Error Resume Next
        If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse And shapeName(ActivePresentation.Slides(i), "NameofShapeonSlide") Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Export filenamepng & "SlideName" & i & ".png", "PNG"

        End If
    i = i + 1
    Next
Next
```